# Query about jenkins in linux

Tags: jenkins, devops

I am having problem with the executor in jenkins.
Can anyone please tell me about executor in jenkins?
Also, explain it's practical implementation.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what is your target state? Please also specify the means you are using? And don't forget to add short sample of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually there is no specific target state. I just wanted to know about the details of this. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from : [Jenkins User Documentation Home - Glossary](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/)

Executor: A slot for execution of work defined by a Pipeline or Project on a Node. A Node may have zero or more Executors configured which corresponds to how many concurrent Projects or Pipelines are able to execute on that Node.

An Executor does "the work" of executing the job steps. In our configuration, we have many nodes, each one corresponding to a VM host / server. We have each node configured with one executor per core. That let's us run one job per core, which is a generally good performance balance. That gives use the ability to run n jobs in parallel on an n-core VM. There are no rules regarding the ratios, depends really on what your jobs do and where the performance issues may be.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the detailed answer.

Comment: @avinash-annand, normally the timely and appropriate acknowledgment as a S/O user would be to up vote the answer if you found it helpful. If you are the person who posted it and found it answered your question, then it would also be appropriate to mark it as answered (the tick mark). Nevertheless, you're welcome.